# Why do I need to remove relationships before deleting an object in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a program in which I'm using CoreData to manage both permanent and temporary data.

In one instance, I abort the addition of some data by deleting the object when the user presses cancel.  But when I hit the next view, the data is still there, attached to it's parent core data object.

```
    [self.bar removeFoosObject:self.foo];//Why do I need this line?
    [self.foo.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.foo];
```

I eventually solved this by manually removing the child object from it's parent -- but isn't that something core data handles automatically?  Why should I need the first line?

I ran some test code, and Foo is definitely deleted -- the code that it was mucking up let me check, and it's MOC has been set to nil.  The memory exists, but it should be very, very dead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually do this because you have your deletion rules set wrong. Check the Relationship Delete Rules in the following apple documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Or it could also be that the relationship is NOT set as optional between the parent and child object.

And also after you delete the object you should save the database to synchronize it.

Comment: Hrm... I'll check the delete rules, but I would have thought that a deleted object would be removed from it's parents anyway.  As for saving the database... given that I never saved it into existence, why bother?

Comment: Delete rule for child is to nullify, which is correct.  Child is also set with a non-optional rule to parent, which is correct.  Parent has it's relationship marked as cascade/optional, but that shouldn't matter here.

Comment: When you save the object all of the relations are checked, if you are using core data the elements should be saving themselves in their persistant store by saving the managed context. When you save all the relations are checked, here is when the auto delete relation is done. You cant expect it to magically happen like in objective C since they are not objects, they are entities of a database. So if you delete the object and then save the context then the parent relationship should get nullified.

Comment: This behavior works like this so that you can delete a relation of a child even when there is a Non-Optional relation to of parent to a child of this type, so that you can set another child to take place for the deleted one before you save.  Like the last part says "or if you ensure that you set a new department for each of the employees before the next save operation." in the nullify section, when the relation is non optional.